# WebKit browsers slow to update canvas

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, webkit

I've created a simple binary clock in javascript, using Canvas, and in Chrome/Safari even though I'm drawing to the canvas many times every second it only updates the screen exactly once per second.

FireFox is updating the instant I draw to the canvas, and I think my code is efficient (activity monitor says the browser is using 5% to 10% of a single CPU core while the animation is running).

How can I make webkit browsers update more often? My actual code is at jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mqGKR/

But basically this is what I'm doing:

```
function updateCanvas()
{
  if (!canvasNeedsUpdating()) {
    return;
  }

  var ctx = blockView.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  if (canvasNeedsFill()) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1.0)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  window.setTimeout(updateCanvas, 10);
}
```

Comment: I confirm your findings.  The last few webkit releases have had poor canvas performance and also unexpected glitches.  :(

Comment: Just a Try...Does it speed up if you clear using canvas.width=canvas.width instead of ctx.clearRect?

Comment: @markE I tried that but it didn't help. I don't think it's a performance issue, I think it's intentional behaviour in WebKit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow. This gets weird.

This has nothing to do with canvas. It has to do with your BinaryTime class. There's some difference in the functioning of the Date objects between at least Chrome and Firefox.

The `beginning` and `end` are `1370318400000` and `1370404800000` in FireFox. Every time. Presumably this is what you want looking at the comments.

They are changing every single time in Chrome, which means they are definitely not representing midnight this morning and midnight tonight as your comments suggest.

In other words, the Date object in Chrome/webkit *appears* broken. But it's more accurate. It's less accurate in Firefox in a more subtle way, but for now lets focus on a fix. (Later tonight, while crying into a tub of ice cream, I'll submit some bug reports).

But Chrome is doing the right thing here, because you are **not** calling `setMilliseconds` and chrome is respecting that. Firefox gets weird and does the wrong thing, but it just so happens to be what you want.

So anyway, the easy way that works off the bat is to use `setHours` with all four arguments:

```
// init "beginning" timestamp as midnight this morning
var beginning = new Date();
beginning.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
beginning = beginning.getTime();

// init "end" timestamp as as midnight tonight
var end = new Date(date);
end.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
end = end.getTime();
```

I'd just do that for now. Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvR6H/

The slightly-more-drawn-out problem is that in Chrome/WebKit you **need** to also set the milliseconds:

`blah.setMilliseconds(0);`

You need to set it in FireFox too, you're exploiting a sort-of Firefox bug as your code is written right now. It *would* be "broken" in Firefox too if you had `beginning = new Date()`, in other words with an empty constructor. See here for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/VbWnk/

It just so happens that new Date(new Date()) in Firefox trims off the milliseconds for you. Actually, to be fair, IE works the same way so Chrome/Webkit is the odd one out. The ECMAScript specification is not clear on who's right (FF/IE seem to be right, but talk for EcmaScript 6 indicate they may special case `new Date(Date)`. A Date object is not technically an acceptable argument to the Date constructor, but a string is, and the Date string does not contain milliseconds. This suggests FireFox/IE are more correct, but WebKit's way is understandable too, and may be right in the future.

...But anyway, `setHours(a,b,c,d)` sets the hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds as shorthand, so that's easier to write.

Hope your project goes well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is actually Firefox with the bug. [ECMA Spec for Date](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) Unless I am reading it wrong, it should be specifying as `0` for milliseconds automatically by spec. Great that you found the issue though, it is still pretty obscure.

Comment: Yes apparently there was discussion about making it special case `new Date(Date)` in ECMAScript 6 talk. See comment here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=868496#c2

Comment: Ahhh ok. The date object has always been a little odd to work with having various bugs and cross-browser problems. Hopefully version 6 does address some of these differences though I wouldn't expect it to be in our browsers for quite some time (FF is only starting to implement version 5 functions like `.map`)

Comment: Wow thanks! It's working great. I mostly use this binary clock as a way to test various different programming languages... you could call it my hello world for graphical software. Also this is far from the weirdest bug I've found in javascript's date handling... ugh.